# Is a principal bundle of a principal bundle still principal?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, fiber-bundles, principal-bundles

Let $\left(P_1,\pi_1,M,G_1\right)$ and $\left(P_2,\pi_2,P_1,G_2\right)$ be two principal bundles, where $M$, $P_1$ and $P_2$ are differential manifolds, and $G_1$ and $G_2$ are Lie groups. With these settings, the chain
$$
P_2\xrightarrow{\pi_2}P_1\xrightarrow{\pi_1}M
$$
would induce
$$
\pi_1\circ\pi_2:P_2\to M.
$$

My questions are:

(1) Is this $\pi_1\circ\pi_2$ always a principal bundle, and

(2) In the case where $\pi_1\circ\pi_2$ is a principal bundle, is its structure group always $G_1\times G_2$?

***Motivation***. That $\pi_1\circ\pi_2$ is always a fiber bundle seems straightforward, but I am curious as to whether this hierarchical system preserves the Lie group structure (especially if it does in the direct-product fashion).

Thank you!

Comment: I seem to remember that, indeed, $\pi_1\circ \pi_2$ need not be a fiber bundle. But it's been many decades since I figured out a counterexample.

Comment: @Ted:  According to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/74611/is-the-composition-of-two-bundle-projections-necessarily-a-bundle-projection, when the spaces are manifolds, such a composition is a fiber bundle map.  (But for more general spaces, you are right that it need not be.)

Comment: I'm not sure about (1), but (2) doesn't always hold. For example, take the non-trivial double cover of the circle. It is a group, but not isomorphic to the product $S^1\times\mathbb{Z}/2$.

Comment: @TedShifrin: Dear Ted: Thanks a lot for your comment. Er... Yes, I was following Jason (@Jason DeVito) that $M$, $P_1$ and $P_2$ are all differential manifolds here.

Comment: @JasonDeVito: Dear Jason: Thank you very much for your comment. The previous question you mentioned is really helpful. I regret to have put it that the composition is still a bundle mapping is "straightforward". I misused the local triviality there, as I merely focused on the pre-image of a single point in $M$ and in $P_1$.

Comment: @AmitaiYuval: Dear Amitai: Many thanks for your inspiring comment. I am not sure if I got it correctly in the Lie group case; here is my understanding. Let $\pi_1:P_1\to M$ be such that, locally on $M$, there is a circle structure $S^1$. Let $\pi_1\circ\pi_2:P_2\to M$ be such that, locally on $M$, there is a Klein bottle structure $K$. The choice of $\pi_2:P_2\to P_1$ is made such that, locally on $P_1$, there is a circle structure $S^1$. With this construction, $G_1\times G_2$ corresponds to $S^1\times S^1$, which is not isomorphic to $K$. Does this interpret your idea? Thank you very much!

Comment: @hypernova I am talking about something simpler than that. Let me give more details. The circle, $S^1$, is a principal circle bundle over a point. Let $P$ denote the non-trivial double cover of the circle. Then $P$ is a principal $\mathbb{Z}/2$ bundle over the circle. Now, $P$ is actually a ("bigger") circle itself, and, in particular, $P$ is also a principal bundle over a point. However, the structure group is $S^1$, and not the direct product $S^1\times\mathbb{Z}/2$.

Comment: @AmitaiYuval: Dear Amitai: Thanks a lot for your clarification. I got it. This is a perfect and simple example. I was making it a bit complicated as I was hoping to have an example where $M$, $P_1$ and $P_2$ are all differentiable manifolds, and $G_1$ and $G_2$ are both Lie groups. In your example, a single point might not be a differentiable manifold, and the modulo $\mathbb{Z}/2$ group seems not a Lie group. That is why I turned to Klein bottle. But of course, all credits go to your inspiring example! Thank you very much :-)

Comment: @hypernova I would say that a single point is indeed a manifold, as well as the group $\mathbb{Z}/2$.

Comment: @AmitaiYuval: Hello Amitai: Oh yes, you are right! Thanks for correcting me.